# Laravel Echo callback

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm looking into Laravel Echo (With socket.io as connector)

But I can't find out how to bind a **callback** when user/visitor succeed or not connecting to the socket (Not channel), but generally if connected.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"; //import Laravel-echo

if(typeof(io) != 'undefined'){ //check if io loaded
    //init Echo
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: { path: '/socket.io' }
    });
}
```

So here I do check if **io** exist, then most probably socket is up.

But can we bind a callback like we can do with socket.io:
Example from socket.io docs

```
const socket = io('http://localhost');

console.log(socket.id); // undefined

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // 'here we can get socket id'
});
```

The reason why I need a callback is to get the socket id and initiate other scripts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking deeper into the laravel echo source code, I've found that there is `on` event binder, that we can't call straight away `echo.on('connect', ...)`. But we have access to connector and the actual socket so here is the solution:

```js
if(typeof(io) != 'undefined'){ //check if io loaded
    //init Echo
    echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: { path: '/socket.io' }
    });

    //bind our events
    echo.connector.socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('connected', echo.socketId());
    });
    echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
    echo.connector.socket.on('reconnecting', function(attemptNumber){
        console.log('reconnecting', attemptNumber);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to figure out how to return a promise from a Presence channel `here` connection, the following worked for me:

```js
// return a promise and resolve when the subscription has succeeded
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    echo.connector.channels['presence-' + channel].subscription.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', () => {
        return resolve(true);
    });
});
```